# Synthesizer suggestions?

Tags: keyboard, instruments, synthesizer

I'm looking for an analog polyphonic synthesizer. I'm really torn between the Moog Matriarch and the David Smith Prophet Rev2. I've not owned a synth before and really want to branch into that world. I like the synth sounds of The Decemberists and Alvvays specifically. I also like the tone of the Synthesizers playlist on Spotify. I know Jenny (Decemberists) uses a Prophet Rev2.

What are some other models I should consider? What are some aspects in general I should think about? I don't live in an area with a large enough music store with several models, so I'm mostly confined to online retail.

This will be for a small home studio with piano, drums, guitar, bass, and MIDI. I'm looking to begin writing/producing my own music. My aim is fairly indie tones.

Comment: Hi! Welcome on MPTSE! Questions asking for material recommendations are considered off topic and will likely be closed soon. You can try to rephrase it in a more general so that the provided answers will be useful to other people than only you. Also, if it's your first synth, have you consider trying a few emulations on a computer with a midi keyboard to have a first view?

Comment: Although the question is closed, hopefully you can read this answer.  I recommend another option-- using a laptop with a DAW and some software synths.  Then you can either use an existing digital MIDI keyboard, or purchase a new keyboard based on playability rather than based on its synth software.

Comment: Software synths in DAWs have a serious danger: distraction. Software makers want to offer instant gratification, "easy" things, features, millions of gigaloads of presets and material, _downloadable_ this and that, and some of the stuff looks like a music related social networking service where your role is to Like and Buy and Feel Social and Buy. That's the wrong way! Do you want to learn? Pick something, start using it, concentrate on that one thing and don't care about what others say. Only your skills count, and you build skills only by practicing.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica I completely agree with you, after spending some time playing with that I now have a big tendency to go toward "simpler" hardware synths! Spending more time into knowing them well and more time in music! Maybe emulations, if you are aware that you want to buy hardware in the end can just help figure out a "type" of synth to start with?

Comment: Technically the Matriarch is paraphonic, which really won't behave the same as an actual poly synth. The only true poly Moog is the Moog One, which seems to be plagued with technical issues despite its eye-watering price. The main contenders for true poly analog synths are Sequential/Dave Smith (e.g., the Prophet synths), Arturia (on the PolyBrute), and Korg (the Minilogue). Yes I'm leaving out Behringer - if you really want to invest in a true analog poly synth I think you'll find those lacking, but if you're less skeptical you can consider them also.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I couldn't find the rules page for this forum. I appreciate the suggestions.